# get id of Json object using the intent , do a web query to get details (in json object) and then update the UI

Tags: android, json, listview, android-intent

I have two activities...In first activity its a list view where i get the data from the Json file....now when user click on an item of the list view a new activity should open...so i pass the id from activity 1 to activity 2 using an intent. Instead of sending all the details using intent is there any other way that i can only pass the id to activity 2 and then query json file to get details (json object) and then update the UI.

Here is my code.

## **Activity 1:-**

```
package activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

/**
 * Created by on 11/25/15.
 */
public class ProductsList extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = ProductsList.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
//    private static final String url = "http://*.*.*.*:0000/android_login_api/toys.json"; //home
    private static final String url = "http://*.*.*.*:0000/android_login_api/toys.json"; //starbucks
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.products_list_view);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                Movie item = (Movie) adapter.getItem(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(ProductsList.this, ProductDetailInformation.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", item.getId().toString());
//                intent.putExtra("name", item.getTitle().toString());
//                intent.putExtra("price", item.getPrice().toString());
//                Bundle reviews = new Bundle();
//                reviews.putDouble("rating", ((Number) item.getRating()).doubleValue());
//                intent.putExtras(reviews);
//                intent.putExtra("description", item.getDescription().toString());
//
//                //send image
//                BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) ((NetworkImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail))
//                        .getDrawable();
//                Bitmap bitmap=bd.getBitmap();
//                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//                bd.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
//                byte[] imgByte = baos.toByteArray();
//                intent.putExtra("image", imgByte);

                //based on item add info to intent
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

//        // changing action bar color
//        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
//                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setAddtocart(obj.getInt("addtocart"));

                                movie.setDescription(obj.getString("description"));
                                movie.setId(obj.getString("id"));
                                // movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image1"));
                                // Price is json array
//                                JSONArray priceArry = obj.getInt("price");
//                                ArrayList<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
//                                for (int j = 0; j < priceArry.length(); j++) {
//                                    price.add((String) priceArry.get(j));
//                                }
                                movie.setPrice(obj.getString("price"));

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);


        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                //ProductsList.this.listView.getFilter().filter(cs);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = inputSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**

### Activity 2:

**

```
package activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import adapter.CustomListAdapter;
import model.Movie;
import puerile.toystore.com.R;

/**
 * Created by on 12/3/15.
 */
public class ProductDetailInformation extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = ProductDetailInformation.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
//    private static final String url = "http://*.*.*.*:0000/android_login_api/toys.json"; //home
      private static final String url = "http://*.*.*.*:0000/android_login_api/toys.json"; //starbucks

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    TextView price;
    TextView rating;
    NetworkImageView image;
    TextView id;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
        rating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
        description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        image = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);


        Intent intent = getIntent();

//        String headerInfo = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
//        String priceInfo = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
////        String addtocartInfo = intent.getExtras().getString("addtocart");
//        Bundle userdata = intent.getExtras();
//        double result = userdata.getDouble("rating");
//        String detailInfo = intent.getExtras().getString("description");
//        // String ratingInfo = intent.getExtras().getString("rating");
//        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
//        byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("image");
//        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
//        BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);

        String idInfo = intent.getExtras().getString("id");

//        title.setText(headerInfo);
//        price.setText(priceInfo);
////        title.setText(addtocartInfo);
//        String stringdouble = Double.toString(result);
//        rating.setText(stringdouble);
//        description.setText(detailInfo);
//        image.setBackground(background);
        id.setText(idInfo);


        hidePDialog();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the person who gave -1 does not even understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a proper endpoint to get the toy details. Normally passing the id as a REST path (android_login_api/toys/) or in the query string (android_login_api/toys?id=), there are multiple options.

If you have only the endpoint with the list of toys, instead of passing only the id to the Activity2, you can also use the intent to send the json section of the toy which user have been selected, as a string. So, Activity2 will receive the json data in the intent data.

Anyway, I extremely recommend you to use a serialisation library, such as GSON or Jackson, to convert JSON into Java classes. It is easy to create a model from JSON objects and configure Volley to return the required model Java class (or list) when you send a Volley request.